# Python Assign Value to New Column If Contains() Is True

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

How can I use the str.contains() method to check a column if it contains specific strings and assign a value if true in a different column?  Essentially, I'm trying to mimic a CASE WHEN LIKE THEN syntax in SQL but in pandas.  Really new to python and pandas and would appreciate any help!  Essentially, I want to search 'Source' for either video, audio, default, and if found, then Type would be video, audio, default accordingly.  I hope this makes sense!

```
Source                 Type
video1393x2352_high    video
audiowefxwrwf_low      audio
default2325_none       default
23234_audio            audio
```

Comment: use `find` in string or you can use `re` for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the str.extract method ... takes a regular expression as an argument ... returns matched group as a string ...

```
df['Type'] = df.Source.str.extract('(video|audio|default)')
```

For some case sensitivity you could add ...

```
df['Type'] = df.Source.str.lower().str.extract('(video|audio|default)')
```

Example, including a non match follows ...

```
In [24]: %paste
import pandas as pd

data = """
Source
video1393x2352_high
audiowefxwrwf_low
default2325_none
23234_audio
complete_crap
AUDIO_upper_case_test"""

from StringIO import StringIO # import from io for python 3
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), header=0, index_col=None)

df['Type'] = df.Source.str.lower().str.extract('(video|audio|default)')
## -- End pasted text --

In [25]: df
Out[25]: 
                  Source     Type
0    video1393x2352_high    video
1      audiowefxwrwf_low    audio
2       default2325_none  default
3            23234_audio    audio
4          complete_crap      NaN
5  AUDIO_upper_case_test    audio
```

Comment: this was a lot simpler than i thought. i did notice though that the extract values tend to be case sensitive, which was a quick tweak.  thank you very much!

Comment: A word of caution: This method does not work for multiples (ie. if a Source contains both the words video and audio). In the multiple case, the code above will only return the first match. It will depend on your data whether this is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `numpy.where` or `pandas.DataFrame.where`. Both take a boolean array and conditionally assign based on that.

```
In [4]: np.where([True, False, True], 3, 4)
Out[4]: array([3, 4, 3])
```

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html

You would construct the boolean array using str.contains, and then pass it to the where method.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:-

```
import re
input_values = ['video1393x2352_high', 'audiowefxwrwf_low', 'default2325_none', '23234_audio']
pattern = re.compile('audio|video|default') 
res_dict = {}
for input_val in input_values:
    type = pattern.findall(input_val)
    if type:
        res_dict[input_val] = type[0]

print res_dict #{'23234_audio': 'audio', 'audiowefxwrwf_low': 'audio', 'video1393x2352_high': 'video', 'default2325_none': 'default'}
```